# pyQt, list passed to class init

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm new to Python and pyQt. I've got a class for a QDialog, and am passing a list of strings to this class in the init;

```
class Remove_Source(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_R_Source):
    def __init__(self, items=None):
        super(Remove_Source , self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_R_Source()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Remove Source Folders")
        self.items = items or []
        for i in range(self.items.count()):
            self.ui.keep_window.addItem(self.items(i))
        self.exec()
```

The list is inaccessible within the class. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your syntax. Some points you need to check:

1) [count](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) has a different meaning for a Python list than it has for a QList. The equivalent for a python list is `len(self.items)` (for example).

2) The [indexation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) operator (as in C++) is `[]`. The `()` would be a [call](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) operation (like in a function and its arguments). In your code this means changing `self.items(i)` to `self.items[i]`.

```
class Remove_Source(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_R_Source):
    def __init__(self, items=[]):                      # changed here
        super(Remove_Source , self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_R_Source()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Remove Source Folders")
        self.items = items
        for i in range(len(self.items)):               # changed here
            self.ui.keep_window.addItem(self.items[i]) # changed here
        self.exec()
```

As a final note, although not invalid, using [logical operators](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) to provide a value might get you into trouble eventually. In your case in here `items or []` you are assuming that `items` has a truth value. This is Ok if you are aware of what is happening but it can be dangerous otherwise. In the code I gave the default value as an empty list `[]` and performed the normal attribution operation `self.items = items`. I think its more explicit and safe (generally speaking).

In any case try these modifications and see if it solves the problem.